# How to read from multiple dbf files in a single query

Tags: c#, sql, dbf

I am trying the following query to read from multiple dbf files in the same folder:

```
"SELECT COMPNO FROM REF10,REF11,REF12,REF08,REF09 WHERE SR_NO='RDDFT000108'";
```

The above generates the following error:

> "The specified field 'COMPNO' could refer to more than one table
>   listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement."

How can I refer more than one tables in the same query?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `UNION`

```
SELECT COMPNO  FROM REF10 WHERE SR_NO='RDDFT000108';
UNION ALL;
SELECT COMPNO  FROM REF11 WHERE SR_NO='RDDFT000108';
UNION;
SELECT COMPNO  FROM REF12 WHERE SR_NO='RDDFT000108';
UNION;
SELECT COMPNO  FROM REF08 WHERE SR_NO='RDDFT000108';
UNION;
SELECT COMPNO  FROM REF09  WHERE SR_NO='RDDFT000108';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use table definitions in the query text:

```
"SELECT REF10.COMPNO, REF11.COMPNO, REF12.COMPNO, REF08.COMPNO, REF09.COMPNO FROM REF10,REF11,REF12,REF08,REF09 WHERE SR_NO='RDDFT000108'";
```